# Does "enable runtime themes" affect performance?

Tags: delphi, themes, delphi-2007

I've recently changed "enable runtime themes" value in the project options and I'm wondering if it's value affects application's performances and, in case, in which manner?
Hope someone can clarify me this point.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't have any impact on performance in my app. I don't know what your app does so it's hard to predict whether it matters for you. Almost certainly it does not matter. Did you profile?

Comment: Are you measuring performance? If so, then change the setting, measure again, and compare the results to get your answer. If you're not, then I don't see how the answer to this question matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What "Enable runtime themes" actually does is telling Windows to [Enable Visual Styling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx) of the applications via following manifest entry

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

You could also have runtime themes enabled in older Delphi versions using different methods. Delphi 7 included `TXPManifest` component that had same effect as "Enable runtime theme".

Enabling runtime themes has impact on GUI part of the application. Obviously painting flat Win 95 style button should be more performant that painting gradient styled rounded Win XP/Vista/Win7 button, but as noted by @DavidHeffernan and @TLama that may not be so. One of the problems here is also measuring actual performance, since it can depend on many factors. So even if you do some actual performance profiling results can be highly skewed. Real question here is should difference in GUI performance between non-themed and themed application (no matter which one turns out to be faster) be of some concern to you.

Answer to that part would be no. First, any performance impacts you may have are strictly GUI related. Second, static Windows application GUI is far less demanding than any 3D game our computers are fully capable to run. And since visual styling has been introduced with Windows XP and back then computers did not have any performance problems in handling styles (it is used all over the system) dwelling about runtime themes performance in today's apps running on modern hardware is just waste of time.

Comment: It's even plausible that themed painting is faster then non-themed. It's plausible that the former is optimized and the latter is not.

Comment: It's difficult to say whether rendering of a single application without themes will improve its performance in a themed environment. DWM uses hardware acceleration (through DirectX) for its rendering, so it's supposed to be efficient. The question is rather how difficult is for this environment rendering non-themed app.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, it is plausible that it is the other way around. There is another consideration with themes and that is Windows border transparency that does have some performance impact if Aero theme is used.

Comment: @TLama I have rephrased the answer. Main point of my answer is not related to whether themed apps will be slower than non-themed apps or the other way around, but the fact this really is not something OP should be concerned about.